# Scrapy Restart Crawler using Multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to write a code which can start scrapy process multiple times, As twisted reactor cannot be restarted, I am trying to spawn a new process using multiprocessing module targeting a function with all scrpay imports in the function. Below is the code I am using.

```
class LniSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    def __init__(self):
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)

class BaseHelper():
    SPIDER = LniSpider
    proxies_path = None

    def run_crawler(self,q):
        import scrapy
        from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
        from scrapy import Selector
        from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
        from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
        CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 10
        settings = get_project_settings()
        if self.proxies_path:
            print("Using Proxies from file ", self.proxies_path)
            settings.set("DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES", self.DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES)
            settings.set("RETRY_TIMES", 10)
            settings.set("RETRY_HTTP_CODES", [500, 503, 504, 400, 403, 404, 408])
            settings.set("PROXY_MODE", 0 )
            settings.set("PROXY_LIST", self.proxies_path)
            settings.set("DOWNLOAD_DELAY", 0.050)
            print("---------------------------------\n\n\n\n")
        process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
        self.SPIDER.temp_file_folder =  self.temp_path
        process.crawl(self.SPIDER)
        process.start()
        q.put(True)


    def crawl(self):

        queue = Queue()
        p = Process(target=self.run_crawler, args=(self,queue))
        p.start()
        p.join() 
        result = queue.get()

        self.run_crawler()
        with open(self.temp_file_path,"r") as data_file:
            data = json.load(data_file)

        os.remove(self.temp_file_path)

        return data
```

But running this causes error

```
(scraper) E:\scraper>python main.py
  E:\scraper\spiders\lni.py:10: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Importing from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch is deprecated and will no longer be supported in future Scrapy versions. If you just want to connect signals use the from_crawler class method, otherwise import pydispatch directly if needed. See: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1762
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
  Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\scraper\helpers\base_helper.py", line 98, in crawl
  p.start()
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\scraper\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
  self._popen = self._Popen(self)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\scraper\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
  return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\scraper\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
  return Popen(process_obj)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\scraper\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 65, in __init__
  reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\scraper\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
  ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\scraper\lib\socket.py", line 185, in __getstate__
  raise TypeError("Cannot serialize socket object")
  TypeError: Cannot serialize socket object

  (scraper) E:\scraper>Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\scraper\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 99, in spawn_main
  new_handle = reduction.steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\scraper\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 87, in steal_handle
  _winapi.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS | _winapi.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)
  PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

I am running this code on Windows 10 in Anaconda virtual environment, The code works fine in Ubuntu. How can I restart a scraper without restarting the whole script?

Comment: can you try `pythonw main.py` ?

Comment: Well it didn't even start if I use pythonw

Comment: Any firewall or antivirus? If so try disabling it. Also can you try to run in Command prompt with admin rights

Comment: I have already tried it with admin right, it causes the same error and AV is disabled too